# LSTM Regression probnlem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i'm trying to create a model to return the average of a sequence of five numbers, but when i try to run my Vanilla LSTM model returns a huge loss and null (loss: 0.4943 - acc: 0.0000e+00).

i don't know if the problems is in the reshape or in the sequence that i created

```
def generate_data (n_samples, n_features):
    output = []
    target = []
    for j in range (0, n_features):
        lista = [] 
        for i in range (0, n_samples):
            n = random.uniform(0,1)
            lista.append(n)
        output.append(lista)
        aux = np.average(lista)
        target.append((aux))
    return np.array(output), np.array(target)
```

The Reshape part

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],  X_train.shape[1],  1)
X_val = X_val.reshape(  X_val.shape[0],  X_val.shape[1],1)

y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0],1)
y_val = y_val.reshape( y_val.shape[0],1)
```

And the model

```
# define model
vanilla = Sequential()
vanilla.add(LSTM(10, input_shape =(X_train.shape[1:]))) # (5,1)
vanilla.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
# compile the model
vanilla.compile(loss= 'mae' , optimizer= 'adam', metrics = ['acc'])
print(vanilla.summary())
```

Comment: For regression it makes no sense to use a softmax activation, even less with a single neuron (which produces a constant output).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i'm trying to change the model, but nothing happens. 

vanilla.add(LSTM(10, input_shape =(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences = False)) 


vanilla.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

Comment: it is a regression problem, try `activation = 'mse'` (`softmax`and `sigmoid` are better suited for classification problems)

Comment: @BDouchet 
ValueError: Unknown activation function: mse

Comment: `activation=linear` sorry

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the softmax activation function in the final Dense layer, which normalizes all the neurons to be between 0 and 1. Because you only have 1 neuron in the output, the output will always be 1 and thus your loss will always be very high.

To fix this, you should probably use a linear activation (which does not modify the neurons' values) since you are doing a regression task. You can do so by changing this line

`vanilla.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))`

to this

`vanilla.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))`

or this

`vanilla.add(Dense(1))`

since by default the activation will be linear.

Comment: maybe it`s on the input shape?    
print(X_train)
[[[0.12065784]
  [0.37481469]
  [0.07087079]
  [0.47122419]
  [0.11244805]]

 [[0.64390319]
  [0.99240914]
  [0.19983161]
  [0.9593273 ]
  [0.5896457 ]]

Comment: Does the loss go down when you train it for many epochs? Also, instead of using accuracy as a metric, you should use something like mean squared error instead by switching out 'acc' with 'mean_squared_error'. Keras measures accuracy by checking to see if the output of the model is exactly equal to the labels so you will always have an accuracy of 0. You can find other potentially useful regression metrics here: https://keras.io/api/metrics/regression_metrics/.